# Set data by response from a server

Tags: java, reflection

I need implement a command (part of our protocol), after sending the request I am getting 130 parameters as one string divided by special character.
I want to implement an efficient way in creating several objects depending on this response.
I thought about it and there are two methods I could think of:

1. The naive way, just define 130~ variables and assign them to the constructors of the objects.
2. I thought of a way to use reflection, each parameter will be assigned by the definition of the object that I want to create. But there are two main issues with this approach:

   1. From my experience I know it would take more time than usually assign variables and allocate objects.
   2. By getting the fields of the object using `data.getClass().getDeclaredFields`the declared files are returned in different order than I am expecting them to be. Is there a way the fields could be returned as declared in the class?

This is the code I done so far:

```
private Object getExamClassData(Class<?> examClass, String[] examFileFrags, int startIndex, int endDataIndex)
{
    ARRefraction data = null;
    try
    {
        Constructor<ARRefraction> ctor = (Constructor<ARRefraction>) ARRefraction.class.getConstructor();
        data = ctor.newInstance();    
        Field[] fields = data.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        int fIndex = 0;
        for (fIndex = 0;fIndex<fields.length;fIndex++)
        {
            try
            {
                Field field = fields[fIndex];
                field.setAccessible(true); 
                if(field.getType().isAssignableFrom(Float.TYPE))
                {
                    field.set(data, Float.parseFloat(examFileFrags[fIndex+startIndex]));
                }
                else if(field.getType().isAssignableFrom(Integer.TYPE))
                {
                    field.set(data, Integer.parseInt(examFileFrags[fIndex+startIndex]));
                }
                else if(field.getType().isAssignableFrom(String.class))
                {
                    field.set(data, examFileFrags[fIndex+startIndex]);
                }

            }
            catch (IllegalArgumentException e1)
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IllegalAccessException e1)
            {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return data;
    }
    catch (java.lang.InstantiationException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IllegalAccessException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (NoSuchMethodException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (InvocationTargetException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;

}
```

ARRefraction object

```
 public class ARRefraction implements Parcelable
{
    private float   _sFar;
    private float   _cFar;
    private int     _aFar;
    private float   _pFar;
    private float   _puFar;

    private float   _sNear;
    private float   _cNear;
    private int     _aNear;
    private float   _puNear;
    private float   _pNear;

    private String  _vaFar;
    private float   _hoFar;
    private float   _qFar;
    //
    private String  _vaNear;
    private float   _hoNear;
    private float   _qNear;

    private float   _add;
}
```

Comment: Just a thought: Put all the data in a `Map<String, String>`. Create an interface with getters. Wrap the 2 with a dynamic proxy. Now each time a new parameter is added all you need is to expose a new getter for it

Comment: Good idea!, What about the first question, there will be an overhead while using reflection